# Delete one smallest element in an array while preserving order in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Simple question, but somehow I can't think of a solution. How can I delete a single smallest element in an array of random integers?

```
a = [7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4]
b = [2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

This is what I come up with:

```
def remove_it(num)
    num.delete(num.sort[0])
end
```

Code works with `a`, but not `b`. It deletes *both* `1`'s in `b`. I only need to delete one `1`.

How can I delete one smallest number in an array and keep the order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy-peasy. Use [`.delete_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) + [`.index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-index):

```
def remove_it(num)
  num.delete_at(num.index(num.min))
  num
end

a = [7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4]
b = [2, 2, 1, 1, 2]

remove_it(a) # => [7, 5, 3, 2, 4]
remove_it(b) # => [2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Readers: "easy-peasy" is the translation of an old Russian saying.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: haha :)

Comment: easy, but only when you know the answer

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: one can surely scan list of available methods in documentation of Array class, and look closer at those with promising names? That's what I do.